# How do I get a variable out of a mongodb query in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to get a variable out of a mongodb query in node.js which would count the number of documents in a collection named `students`

I tried to declare a global variable right before the query and tried to assign the value inside the query function:

```
router.get('/dashboard', loggedin, function (req, res, next) {
// Student is a db object of a collection named students
var std_count

Student.find(function(err, doc) {
  if(err) console.log(err)
  else {
  std_count = doc.length
  }
})

console.log(std_count)

res.render('dashboard', {
  user:req.user
  })
});
```

The `console.log()` always prints `undefined`, but if I put the `console.log()` inside `else{}` block, it prints the correct result.

I need to do 4 more queries like this (say teachers, courses etc.) and send them altogether in `res.render()`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: because `student.find` is asynchronous

Comment: possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose `.find` returns a promise by chaining `.exec` to the end,

```
router.get('/dashboard', loggedin, function (req, res, next) {

    // Student is a db object of a collection named students
    Student.find({})
    .exec()
    .then(data => {

        const std_count = data.length;
        res.render('dashboard', {
            user:req.user
        });
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(500));

});
```

---

Update:

Then you can use await each query and send them lastly in the `res.render`.

```
router.get('/dashboard', loggedin, async function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        const std_count = (await Student.find({}).exec()).length || 0;
        const teachers_count = (await Teachers.find({}).exec()).length || 0;
        const courses_count = (await Courses.find({}).exec()).length || 0;

        return res.render('dashboard', { 
            user: req.user,
            studentCount: std_count,
            teacherCount: teachers_count,
            coursesCount: courses_count
        });

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: I know it would work, but i need to do 4 more queries like this say(teachers, coursers, etc) and send them altogether in `res.render()`. Hope you can understand the situation.

Comment: @10ZKhaled Please update that into the question details